# FLVPlayback 2.5 BIGGER Memory Leak with DynamicStream videos

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flvplayback

I have a project where I load and unload a dozens of FLVPlaybacks. I have the "normal" memory leak which FLVPlayback gives, but when I use a DynamicStream video (using RTMP) the leak is bigger! About 10MB added at each video change.

I'm using all material I have found in internet, like [this](http://www.rphelan.com/2008/09/22/flvplayback-memory-leak-fixed/comment-page-1/#comment-13620), and [this](https://svn2.assembla.com/svn/imajukAsLib/branches/slideShow/src/com/imajuk/display/DisposableFLVPlayback.as) in my dispose method, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: do you have to use the FLVPlayback component? just try and write your own player. then you would have full control over creating and disposing the component. or try using the [osmf](http://blogs.adobe.com/osmf/).

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But the project is almost ready, and solving that memory leak would save a big amount of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found any real solution to my problem, I had to migrate to [OSMF](http://www.osmf.org), and it rocks!